# Should a question asked for finding out error be deleted after solved?

Tags: discussion, deletion, solution-verification

Let's say there is a question I asked to find out the error I made in my solution of a problem.
 Someone then answers, pointing out a "silly error" I made (like simple calculation error, or switching +,- signs).

So after finding out it was a "silly error", should the question be deleted?

The question will serve no purpose as a "useful reference" as it has no learning values, and will be a useless collection of data for the website. It will serve no use to the website or its users other than a "downvote target practice".

What should be the ethical or proper response?

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, if someone posts an answer and the answer is upvoted, then you **can’t** delete the question.  (Correct me if I am wrong.)
2. If someone posts an answer and you find the response helpful, then you should reward the person with an upvote.  See case 1.
3. If someone points out your error in a comment, then the person has consented to providing free advice.  Thus, deletion of the question does not wrong anyone.  You are free to delete it **if** it truly is in fact useless to everyone else.

I’d also like to draw your attention to the comments:

> It should also be mentioned that users, especially new users with little rep, should think twice about deleting questions that have been downvoted. The deletion of heavily downvoted questions seems to be a huge liability and factor in many new users' bans from asking questions. —amWhy

> The point is that we don't want users that asked that bad a question to ask many more questions. The details of the ban criteria are not generally known, not even to moderators, but as @amWhy said a deletion rather counts against a user; as said that's mostly a concern for really new users. If one has ten non-terrible posts and one deletes one, there is no issue. Thus, if it's the first or second post one might wait a bit with deletion, especially if there is no ongoing onslaught of downvotes. —quid♦

Comment: It should also be mentioned that users, especially new users with little rep, should think twice about deleting questions that have been downvoted.  The deletion of  heavily downvoted questions seems to be a huge liability and factor in many new users' bans from asking questions.

Comment: @amWhy I didn’t know that. Why is that? If a question is that bad, don’t we want it gone?

Comment: The point is that we don't want users that asked that bad a question to ask many more  questions. The details of the ban criteria are not generally known, not even to moderators,  but as @amWhy said a deletion rather counts against a user; as said that's mostly a concern for really new users. If one has ten non-terrible posts and one deletes one, there is no issue. Thus, if it's the first or second post one might wait a bit with deletion, especially if there is no ongoing onslaught of downvotes.